# Freely available dictionary data for Chinese, Japanese, CJK characters

Tags: dictionary, unicode, internationalization

I am developing an online CJK character dictionary application, and already found the following databases:

- [Unicode Unihan Database](http://www.unicode.org/)
- Jim Breen's [JMDict](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/jmdict.html) and [KanjiDic](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/kanjidic2/)
- [CEDict](http://cc-cedict.org/wiki/start)
- [HanDeDict](http://www.chinaboard.de/chinesisch_deutsch.php?mode=intro)

As I am looking for more data, web searches often lead me to online dictionaries, but not the data itself, using the same sources over again.

If you know of any CJK-relevant downloadable dictionaries, please add them.

Answer (score 3):

Also:

[The Tatoeba Project](http://tatoeba.org/home) - community based corpus, growing all the time

Answer (score 0):

If you're not confining yourself to character-specific dictionaries, you should take a look at:

[Gene 95](http://www.namazu.org/~tsuchiya/sdic/data/gene.html) - an English-Japanese dictionary which seems to be freely available now.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

- [Wadoku](http://www.wadoku.de/) German/Japanese dicionary
- [IPADic and Unidic](http://chasen-legacy.sourceforge.jp/) Japanese Part-of-speech dictionaries

Comment: JMDict gets its German part from Wadoku, so you don't need to use it separately if you already have JMDict.